# Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined?how can i push the numbers to first drop down list ? using java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var select = document.getElementById("source"); 
var select2= document.getElementById("status");
var option = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8","9"];
var option2= [];
function moveright()
{
var a = source.options[source.selectedIndex].value;
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = a;
select2.add(option);
select.remove(i);
}
function moveleft()
{
var b = status.option2[status.selectedIndex].value;
var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.text = b;
select.add(option2);
select2.remove(i);
}
for(i = 0; i < option.length; i++) 
{
var opt = option[i];
var a = document.createElement("option");
a.innerHTML = opt;
a.value = opt;
select.appendChild(a);
}
for(i = 0; i < option2.length; i++) 
{
var opt2 = option2[i];
var a = document.createElement("option");
a.innerHTML = opt2;
a.value = opt2;
select2.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<select id = "source" multiple size = "10" onclick = "moveright ()">
<option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id = "status" multiple size = "10" onclick = "moveleft ()">
<option>Choose a number </option>
</select>
```

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var option = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8","9"];
for(i = 0; i < option.length; i++) 
{
    var opt = option[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
var select = document.getElementById("status"); 
var options = [ ]; 
select.innerHTML = "";
options.push (selectNumber);
for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
 {
    var opt = options[i];
    select.innerHTML += "<option value=\"" + opt + "\">" + opt + "</option>";
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber" multiple size = "10">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id = "status" multiple size = "10"></select>
```

I want to push and remove the elements from the first drop down to second and vice versa ???
I am Getting error "Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined". what is the meaning of this error? can anyone help me?

Comment: `options.push (selectNumber);` What is the value of `selectNumber` here?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you want to do. Do you want the numbers to move to the second select when clicked? And back again, also when clicked?

Comment: yes please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append the `option` of the clicked `select` to the other one. See below:

```
if (event.currentTarget !== event.target)
```

is checked because we don't want to move the select itself. Also you might want to check if the clicked option is not `Choose a number` but that's up to you.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var option = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8","9"];
for(i = 0; i < option.length; i++) 
{
    var opt = option[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
var select2 = document.getElementById("status"); 

function move_1(event)
{
  if (event.currentTarget !== event.target)
  {
    select2.appendChild(event.target);
  }
}

function move_2(event)
{
  if (event.currentTarget !== event.target)
  {
    select.appendChild(event.target);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber" multiple size = "10" onclick="move_1(event)">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id = "status" multiple size = "10" onclick="move_2(event)">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

If you want to use push/slice without appendChild

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var option = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8","9"];
var option2 = [];
for(i = 0; i < option.length; i++) 
{
    var opt = option[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
var select2 = document.getElementById("status"); 
var first_option = "<option>Choose a number</option>";

function reconstruct()
{
  select.innerHTML = select2.innerHTML = first_option;
  
  for (var item of option)
  {
    select.innerHTML += "<option value='"+item+"'>"+item+"</option>";
  }

  for (var item of option2)
  {
    select2.innerHTML += "<option value='"+item+"'>"+item+"</option>";
  }
}

function move(event, direction)
{
  if (event.currentTarget === event.target)
  {
    return;
  }
  else if (direction == "right")
  {
    var index = option.indexOf(event.target.value);
    option2.push(event.target.value);
    option.splice(index,1);
    console.log(index);
  }
  else if (event.currentTarget !== event.target && direction == "left")
  {
    var index = option2.indexOf(event.target.value);
    option.push(event.target.value);
    option2.splice(index,1);
    console.log(index);  
  }
  reconstruct();
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber" multiple size = "10" onclick="move(event, 'right')">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id = "status" multiple size = "10" onclick="move(event, 'left')">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how can we find the index of a number? can we write this program in another method? by finding the index of selected values and slice,push?

Comment: what do you mean? As in using the value and finding the index of it in the `option` array?

Comment: I mean without appendChild method can use push,slice?

Comment: so you want to push an `option` into the select instead?

Comment: yes I want to push the options into the second drop down by using push, slice by their indexof() methods not by appendchild ?

Comment: @Sai Well you can't since those methods are for javascript arrays only. Unless you want to recreate the entire select each time you push/slice.

Comment: I want javascript array method only can u help me?

Comment: So why can't you use appendChild? Or is it that I can use append child but you want to utilise arrays as well? Since you used `appendChild` in your original code anyway

Comment: I just asking it, did,i use push,slice methods with indexof()

Comment: @Sai added something to the bottom.

Comment: I am very new to javascript and I came from the Electrical background I know the syntax but I don't know how to use and when to use so that's why I am asking you to give the code so please help me to learn the javascript, please

Comment: @Sai Check the edit. If you want to learn more about pushing/slicing, you will have to ask another question with that specific problem. Documentation and experimenting on jsfiddle is the other alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your patience towards me thanks a lot.I have another doubt can I use FOR LOOP for an empty array and write the program?

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstSelect = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var otherSelect = document.getElementById("status");

var option = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8","9"];
for(i = 0; i < option.length; i++) 
{
    var opt = option[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
function addOption(val){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = val;
    return option;
}
firstSelect.onchange = function(){
    otherSelect.add(addOption(firstSelect.value));
    firstSelect.remove(firstSelect.selectedIndex);
};

otherSelect.onchange = function(){
    firstSelect.add(addOption(otherSelect.value));
    otherSelect.remove(otherSelect.selectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it also sorts the numbers when moving them:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
{
  var opt = options[i];
  $('#selectNumber optgroup').append(
    $('<option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>').click(optionClicked)
  );
}

function optionClicked() {
  var $option = $(this);
  $option.prop("selected", false);
  if($option.parent()[0] === $('#selectNumber optgroup')[0]) {
    $option.appendTo('#status optgroup');
    sort('#status');
  } else {
    $option.appendTo('#selectNumber optgroup');
    sort('#selectNumber');
  }
}

function sort(id) {
  var sel = $(id);
  var selected = sel.val();
  var optgroup = sel.find('optgroup');
  var opts_list = optgroup.find('option');
  opts_list.remove();
  opts_list.sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1; });
  optgroup.append(opts_list);
  optgroup.find('option').click(optionClicked);
  sel.val(selected);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectNumber" multiple size = "10">
    <optgroup label="Choose a number"></optgroup>
</select>
<select id = "status" multiple size = "10">
  <optgroup label="Statuses"></optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: how can we find the index of a number? can we write this program in another method? by finding the index of selected values and slice,push?